# Ruby: concat fields from a hash based on specified order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
data = {"B"=>"bb", "C"=>"cc", "A"=>"aa", "D"=>"dd", "E"=>"", "F"=>nil}
fields_to_select = ["A", "B", "C"]
str = data.select { |elem| fields_to_select.include? elem }.values.compact.reject(&:empty?).join(', ')
```

This would currently return `bb, cc, aa` since that is the order it's in the data hash.

**Is there anyway way to create the string based on the order in `fields_to_select`?**

So that it returns `aa, bb, cc`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes...possible using [`Hash#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at)

```
data = {"B"=>"bb", "C"=>"cc", "A"=>"aa", "D"=>"dd", "E"=>"", "F"=>nil}
fields_to_select = ["A", "B", "C"]
data.values_at(*fields_to_select).join(', ')
# => "aa, bb, cc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Granted, `values_at` is cool stuff, but this problem can also be solved by a garden-variety use of our very old friend `map`.

```
fields_to_select.map { |k| data[k] }.join(', ')
```

Comment: Do you like `fields_to_select.map(&data.method(:[])).join(', ')` ? :)